# Order Statistics problem: why doesn't law of total expectation (Adam's law) work?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, order-statistics

This is the problem

> The opening prices per share, $Y_1$ and $Y_2$, of two similar stocks
>   are independent random variables, each with a density function given
>   by $$f (y) = \frac{1}{2}\exp{\left(\frac{y−4}{2}\right)}\quad\text{where}\  y \ge 4.$$
>
> On a given morning, an investor is going to buy shares of whichever
>   stock is less expensive. Find the expected cost per share that the
>   investor will pay.

The answer is $5$, and I got it by finding the pdf of $\min(Y_1,Y_2)$ and integrating for the expected value. However, I tried using the law of total expectation and I keep getting $6$. This is what I've been doing:

Let $P = \min(Y_1,Y_2)$, then

\begin{align}
E(P) &= E(P|Y_1 \lt Y_2)P(Y_1 \lt Y_2) + E(P|Y_2 \lt Y_1)P(Y_2 \lt Y_1) \\
     &= \frac{1}{2}\int yf(y) dy  + \frac{1}{2}\int yf(y) dy \\
     &= 6
\end{align}

What I've been thinking is that I am ignoring the case where $Y_1=Y_2$ and that is causing me to get the wrong answer, but isn't it true that given two i.i.d. RVs, the probability that one finishes before the other is $1/2$ by the principle of symmetry? What is wrong here with my reasoning?

Comment: Hint: $$\Pr\left(Y_1 < Y_2\right) = \int\limits_{4}^{\infty}\int\limits_{x}^{\infty}f_{Y_1, Y_2}(x,y)\text{ d}y\text{ d}x$$

Comment: Do you _have_ to use $P$ to denote the minimum of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$? Couldn't any _other_ letter work as well? Because now you have the monumental silliness of $$E(P) = E(P|Y_1 \lt Y_2)P(Y_1 \lt Y_2) + E(P|Y_2 \lt Y_1)P(Y_2 \lt Y_1)$$ where sometimes $P$ means the minimum as in $E[P\mid  Y_1 < Y_2]$ and sometimes it means _probability_ as in $P(Y_1 < Y_2)$. -1 pending editing to a more rational question in which a given symbol means the same thing wherever it occurs.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious here, but how does that density $f$ in the quoted question integrate to 1?

Comment: @Glen_b It is a standard integral much beloved by beginning students who tend to be cavalier about negative signs and such. I have been told numerous times that $\exp(-x)\mathbf 1_{x\colon x > 0}$ is not a valid density because we cannot have a negative $x$ in the argument of the exponential function: the $\mathbf 1$ is saying $x$ must "be positive."

Comment: I believe the OP meant for a $4-y$ in his density function.  The integral as written is divergent (it $\rightarrow \infty$ as $y \rightarrow \infty$, but the swap makes it integrate to 1.

Comment: @Matthew Yes, that should make it work ...  I had figured with so many people discussing in the comments and even answering without any concern, that I must actually have missed something along the way.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell that your law of total expectation argument must be wrong intuitively.

Here is your argument worked out in more detail

$$
\begin{align}
E(P) &= E(P|Y_1 \lt Y_2)P(Y_1 \lt Y_2) + E(P|Y_2 \lt Y_1)P(Y_2 \lt Y_1) \\
     &= \frac{1}{2} E(P|Y_1 \lt Y_2) + \frac{1}{2} E(P|Y_2 \lt Y_1) \\
     &= \frac{1}{2} E(Y_1|Y_1 \lt Y_2) + \frac{1}{2} E(Y_2|Y_2 \lt Y_1) \\
     &= \frac{1}{2} E(Y_1) + \frac{1}{2} E(Y_2) \\
     &= E(Y)
\end{align}
$$

But this cannot be correct.  If the buyer takes the cheapest of two equally distributed prices $Y_1$ and $Y_2$, he **must** expect to get a cheaper deal than if he only had one option.

The error is the proposition

$$ E(Y_1|Y_1 \lt Y_2) = E(Y_1) $$

This cannot be true.  For the prior information that $Y_1 < Y_2$ makes it more likely that $Y_1$ assume a small value.

Comment: Does it bother you at all that $P$ means two different things: a probability measure, and a random variable, in your first equation? How can you tell which meaning is to be used where?

Comment: Slightly.  I agree that it's best to avoid having two symbols mean different things in close proximity, but this example is so small that it is clear from context what is meant.